# A continuous, almost nowhere differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity, uniform-convergence

Consider the function $$f(x)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(k^2\pi x\right)}{k^2}.$$ It converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ according to the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) and is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ due to the [uniform limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem).

According to my lecture notes, the termwise differentiated series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \pi \cos (k^2\pi x)$ diverges. It doesn't state for which values of $x$ it diverges, however, using a similar argument as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2250693/642262), I believe it diverges for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (the argument goes like this; whenever $\cos (k^2 \pi x)$ is small, then $k^2 x$ will be close to an odd multiple of $1/2$, and therefor $(2k)^2 x$ will be close to an even multiple of $1/2$ and correspondingly larger).

Now, my lecture notes go on to claim that $f$ in fact is differentiable at some rational points with derivative $-1/2$. I was wondering if this is true and if yes, if it's easy to show (on an undergraduate level). Also, I'd be grateful if you could explain why the linked argument fails to show divergence on all of $\mathbb{R}$, if my lecture notes really are correct.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function#Riemann_function) and [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassFunction.html) for the claim with source.

Comment: @jd27 thanks, that's helpful. How does the function $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(k^2\pi x\right)}{k^2}$ differ from $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(k^2 x\right)}{k^2}$? The Wikipedia article only treats the latter, whereas Hardy seemed to only treat the former.

Comment: *How does the function* $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(k^2\pi x\right)}{k^2}$ *differ from* $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(k^2 x\right)}{k^2}$ --- Isn't this simply a precalculus dilation (i.e. $f(\pi x)$ vs. $f(x))$?

Comment: Ok, no biggie then. Thanks.

Comment: I am still confused about why the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250667/prove-that-sum-k-0-infty-cosk2t-diverges-for-all-t-geq-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) in my question seems to claim that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \cos (k^2 t)$ diverges for $t\geq 0$ when the Wikipedia article claims that [Gerver](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16591735/) found that there are points, namely $\pi(2A+1)/(2B+1)$ (where $A,B$ are integers), where the derivative of $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(k^2 x\right)}{k^2}$ does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sequence of functions converges, and sequence of derivatives converges uniformly, then limit of sequence is differentiable (with derivative equal to limit of derivatives). Converse is not true: it's possible that sequence of derivatives doesn't converge at all, but sum of sequence is still differentiable.

Example from "Counterexamples in analysis": consider $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin nx}{\sqrt n}$. Then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ (which is differentiable) on $[0, 1]$, but $f'_n(x) = \sqrt{n}\cos nx$ which doesn't converge for any $x$.

So, it's possible that series of derivatives diverges, while the original series is still differentiable.